# SublimeText always crash after start

Tags: linux, crash, sublimetext2, fedora, glibc

Sublime suddenly began to fall always after start.

```
*** glibc detected *** sublime: free(): invalid pointer: 0x42197460 ***
```

full: https://gist.github.com/4321825

I have already tried to delete config and rerun sublime and reinstall it but it hadn't any effect.

**glibc version:**

```
Version     : 2.15
Release     : 58.fc17
```

**fedora 17, x32**

**Sublime Text 2 Build 2217**

I also tried all version from here http://repo.cloudhike.com/sublime2_dev/fedora/17/i386/RPMS/
but it have had the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I have found that problem was in package

```
cairo-freeworld.i686 0:1.10.2-1.fc17.R
```

Which have come as dependency of

```
fontconfig-infinality.noarch 3.1-3.R
```

I have just downgrade it to fix my issue.